# Кастомная камера и watermark?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, swift4, watermark

Как мне сделать кастомную камера в'ю, где видео будет сниматся с лимитом в 2.5 мин и при сохранении ставить свой watermark? Смотрел уже много постов на английском, но так и не понимаю как сделать чтобы сделать камеру только для видео 2.5 мин. Спасибо!

Comment: Сделать лимит в 2.5 минуты можно по таймеру, это не проблема. Но вот реализовать watermark на видео не самая простая задача, смотрите в сторону GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)